# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to XmlResourceParser

Tags: java, android, string, xml-parsing, android-external-storage

I'm attempting to read and parse a bit of XML from my internal storage:

```
private void readXML() {
    XmlResourceParser p = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "BootConfiguration";
    try {
        int nextEvent = p.next();
        while (nextEvent != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            nextEvent = p.next();
        }
        processTag(p, p.getName(), new XMLCollector());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        bootconfig = "ERROR: Failed to parse XML!\n" + e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        bootconfig = "ERROR: IOException!\n" + e;
    } finally {
        p.close();
    }

    // TO-DO remove later
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bootconfig);
    t.setText(bootconfig);
}
```

However I'm getting an error stating: `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to XmlResourceParser"` on the line:

```
XmlResourceParser p = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

I've tried changing the XmlResourceParser to a String (as eclipse suggests) however this simply causes more errors further in the code.

### EDIT:

I attempted a shot at the method shown in the first answer below and ended up with this:

```
private void readXML() {
//              XmlPullParser p = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//                              + File.separator + "JvsBootConfiguration";
//             
                InputStream istr = this.getAssets().open(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "JvsBootConfiguration");
                  XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                  factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                  p = factory.newPullParser();
                  p.setInput(istr, "UTF-8");  


                try {
                        int nextEvent = p.next();
                        while (nextEvent != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                                nextEvent = p.next();
                        }
                        processTag(p, p.getName(), new XMLCollector());
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        bootconfig = "ERROR: Failed to parse XML!\n" + e;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        bootconfig = "ERROR: IOException!\n" + e;
                } finally {
                        p.close();
                }
```

However I'm not sure exactly how I should define p (until I figure that out I'm left with 'p cannot be resolved to a variable')

Comment: Read the docs.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. Read internal storage options

Comment: I updated my post above - any suggestions? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "BootConfiguration";
```

returns a String.
You cannot assign a String to a XmlResourceParser.

```
XmlResourceParser  p = "some/directory";
```

is equivalent to trying to assign:

```
int number = "some text";
```

You cannot miss-match types like that.

In your case you need to call a function that returns a XmlResourceParser.
Try:
[android: how to load xml file from assets directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557885/android-how-to-load-xml-file-from-assets-directory)
or
[Create xml on the fly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343509/create-xml-on-the-fly-from-a-string)

Comment: How should p be defined? (updated source shown above)